# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^ka_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$a_n$ has properties 
$a_n\ge a_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$

As the title. I wanted to use the root test(I would appreciate if there is an easier method). So I am trying to find 
$limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\lvert (-1)^na_n}\rvert$

Because of the absolute value, I do not have to deal with $(-1)^n$ so the question is to show $limsup$ of $a_n$ is less than 1. 
I am stuck at this point. Thank you

Comment: Maybe $a_n\ge a_{n+1}$ instead of $0\ge1$?

Comment: @awllower i did not get what you are suggesting

Comment: You wrote $a_n\ge a_n+1$. But now you corrected it, so never mind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is considered a convergence test of its own, called the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

To prove this on its own, consider the even and odd partial sums. First try to prove that they each converge, and then try to prove that they converge to the same value.

Tests like the root test won't work as they depend on the magnitude of the terms; since the series might not necessarily converge absolutely, some proof must depend on the fact that the signs of the series alternate.

Comment: this is a proof class so, i cannot really use that

Comment: @KaanYolsever In that case, one of the proofs on the Wikipedia page should suffice. I can offer some hints if you prefer not to read those proofs in their entirety and have the problem be completely spoiled.

Comment: I would really appreciate that

Comment: @KaanYolsever I added some hints in my answer; hopefully those are helpful.